# React: Defining a JavaScript class for responsive CSS variables

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, responsive-design, styled-components

I'm rebuilding an existing UI in React. It has 4 responsive breakpoints:

1. mobile: has the base styles
2. tablet: inherits mobile styles and then adjusts them for a tablet
3. small desktop: inherits tablet styles and then adjusts them for a small desktop
4. large desktop: inherits small desktop styles, etc.

I am trying to map all of the key CSS values to variables. Ideally, instead of defining a separate variable for each value at each breakpoint, I would like to define one object, for each CSS value, that has the same inheritance properties as the list above.

The way this is constructed in my head would look like (this is pseudo code):

```
class StyleTemplate {
  mobile = ''
  tablet = this.mobile
  small  = this.tablet
  large  = this.small
}

class PageWidth extends StyleTemplate {
  mobile = '100%'
  tablet = '980px'
  large  = '1680px'
}

// PageWidth.small would then return: 980px
```

I'm relatively new to React and ES6, so I would appreciate some help building this method out.

Comment: oh man - you need to watch a intro tutorial on es6 if you want to use it.

Comment: My problem isn’t using ES6. The above is just pseudo code to illustrate my thinking process.

Comment: I think this link will help explain a couple different patterns you can use for this:
https://joshbedo.github.io/JS-Design-Patterns/